# match date from string php preg_match

Tags: php, regex

I have a string:

```
$string = "Created on: 06-Sep-08";
```

I would like to match the date and convert it to 06/09/2008;
what is the needed regexp?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$matches = array();
preg_match('/(\d{2})-(\D*)-(\d{2})/', $string, $matches)
```

This returns the array matches.

> $matches[0] will contain the text that matched the full pattern, $matches[1] will have the text that matched the first captured parenthesized subpattern, and so on

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Comment: this works! thanks a lot. what is the difference between \d and \D?

Comment: `\d` matches digit's and `\D` matches non-digit -characters. A full list can be found at <http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regex#POSIX_character_classes>

Answer (score 3):

```
preg_match('/\:.*/is',...);
```

And then do a

```
strtotime(...)
```

EDIT:

Forgot to add the parantheses

```
preg_match('/\:(.*)/is',$string,$matches);
```

Comment: preg_match('/\:(.*)/is',$string,$matches);